# How to have one div overlap two other divs?

Tags: css, html, overlap

I have a site design I am working on for a bookkeeping service:

http://digitaldemo.net/vintage/home.html

The overall "look" is supposed to be that of a desk blotter. Everything is rendering correctly across the board, but I am having one problem.

I am trying to get the main content area (the "desk blotter") to overlap the top and bottom borders.

The overall page background is a seamlessly tiling image (the lighter brown / gold) and then the top border is a DIV (#section-head) whose background is a semi-transparent PNG and the bottom border DIV (#section-foot) has the same semi-transparent background as well.

My "desk blotter" is inside a #container DIV that uses the following CSS to overlap the top border:

```
#container  { clear:both ;
width:1002px ;
margin:auto ;
background:url("images/paper-bg.jpg") ;
min-height:600px ;
position:relative ;
top:-40px ;
-webkit-box-shadow: #0e0300 0px 0px 14px;
-moz-box-shadow: #0e0300 0px 0px 14px;
box-shadow: #0e0300 0px 0px 14px;
behavior: url("PIE.htc");
z-index:1000 ;
}
```

That works all well and good. Problem is that it forces a gap at the bottom of the #container DIV equal to the -40px top positioning.

So two questions:

a. how do I get rid of that gap; 
b. how do I get the "desk blotter" to overlap the bottom border as well?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand entirely but to get the blotter to overlap the footer you can add this css:

```
#section-foot {
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
}
```

From here you may want to add some padding to the top of the footer if you have any additional content there.

Comment: I had to add margin-bottom:-80px to get rid of the gap that appeared below the bottom border, but thank you for getting me better than halfway there! :)